How to get the new id from a WikiDataId that is redirected?
I am using the MediaWiki API and hav some older Wiki entities that are redirected (e.g.:
Q21840564)
I want to have a programatic approeach to retrieve the redirect target.
Q21840564 -> Q3755886
The redirect is described here:
Wiki Help
I am using the request

GET https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q21840564&format=json

Which results in an "unresolved-redirect" error.
